# Mobile scroll does not work on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, web, mobile, responsive

On mobile devices, scroll down does not work when the services tab is clicked. I can't find the problem for hours. Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `class="page-overlay"` have `position:fixed;`.
If you for example set it to absolute or none all work.

Answer (score 0):

Brand Identity and Online Marketing do work. I opened the developer tools and saw that the div.logo.white is on top of the first two h2. That is probably what causes it, because the functionality works fine. Other than that, great layout and style.

[image]

Comment: unfortunately this is not the problem. I am completely removing the header. the problem persists.

Comment: div.logo.white is blocking your h2 when you scroll. Give it a background-color and you will see.